# Why won't this Javascript auto click work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.todoitem').click(function() {
alert('ok');
}).click();
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>25 Feb 2011</h1>
<h3>ABC</h3>
<ul>
<div>
<a href="http://www.barnsley-chronicle.co.uk" class="todoitem">I want to click here</a>    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm confused. All I need to do is click the link inside the class="todoitem".

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It works perfectly. It shows the alert, then goes to the href mentioned. Which browser do you use?
See http://jsfiddle.net/Z72Xh/

Comment: Yes, I have to agree the code looks fine and it works with the Fiddle above.

Comment: I altered my code, yet this still doesn't work? All it does it stay on the current page. It doesn't load the link inside the class. I tried with Firefox, IE and Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".todoitem").click(function() {
        alert('Item selected');
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });

    $(".todoitem").click();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>25 Feb 2011</h1>
<h3>ABC</h3>
<ul>
<div>
<a href="http://www.barnsley-chronicle.co.uk" class="todoitem">I want to click here</a></div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z72Xh/

Comment: This works, thank you very much.

Big thanks to all who answered. What a great bunch of people. :)

Answer (score 0):

To automate a click, you should do this:

```
$('.todoitem').click();
```

Here's your example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqML7/).

Comment: I altered my code, yet this still doesn't work? All it does it stay on the current page. It doesn't load the link inside the class. I tried with Firefox, IE and Chrome?

Comment: @user1997423, I wasn't sure if you wanted the click to go through to the page. Commenting out the `e.preventDefault();` should work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning onClick function to link with your code, you want to do `$(".target").click();`

Btw first link found on Google for "jquery click on link"

Comment: $("#target") is looking for id="target" and $(".target") looks for class="target". So his code should still work.

Comment: @shaneburgess Ok i used different selector but thats not the point, his code is not clicking on link, its just assigning onClick function to it.

Comment: and btw if he wants to click only on one specific link he realy should use id fot it instead of class

Comment: I altered my code, yet this still doesn't work? All it does it stay on the current page. It doesn't load the link inside the class. I tried with Firefox, IE and Chrome?

Comment: @user1997423 I still think that all you want to do is call $(".todoitem").click();

Comment: Oh, I figured it out now. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't setting a "auto-click". `$('.todoitem').click()` would do what you are looking for.

You are actually setting a listener. So if you click on `.todoitem` it will have that action.

```
$('.todoitem').click()
```

is the functionality you are looking for.

If you need to set the listener and auto click you could do

```
$('.todoitem').click(function() {
    alert('ok');
}).click();
```

Comment: I altered my code, yet this still doesn't work? All it does it stay on the current page. It doesn't load the link inside the class. I tried with Firefox, IE and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do a window.location = ""; after pageload.

Comment: I altered my code, yet this still doesn't work? All it does it stay on the current page. It doesn't load the link inside the class. I tried with Firefox, IE and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".todoitem").click(function() {
        alert('Item selected');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Otherwise you just have no time to see that `'Item selected'` message because after showing the message the browser immediately goes to the URL specified in your link.
The code above cancels the event handling after execution of `alert()`.

And to automatically click the link use the `click()` method as a lot of people mentioned here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".todoitem").click();
});
```

Comment: I altered my code, yet this still doesn't work? All it does it stay on the current page. It doesn't load the link inside the class. I tried with Firefox, IE and Chrome?